# Consolidate response of API's though cast method of Genserver

Tags: api, elixir, erlang-otp

I am trying to call one API 10 times asynchronously though cast method of Genserver. Can someone guide me how I can collect the responses of 10 API and consolidate in one list of tuples?

```
defmodule DataMonitor.RuleReceiver do
  use GenServer

  require Logger

  alias DataMonitor.{
    ProcessRuleSet
  }

  def init(state) do
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [])
  end

  def process_rule_set(receiver_pid, {rule_set, company_id, auth_headers}) do
    GenServer.cast(receiver_pid, {rule_set, company_id, auth_headers})
  end

  def handle_cast({rule_set, company_id, auth_headers}, state) do
    result = ProcessRuleSet.process_rule_set(rule_set, company_id, auth_headers)
    {:noreply, state}
  end

end
```

Sender/Caller module

```
defmodule DataMonitor.RuleSender do
    def perform() do
      Enum.each(rule_sets, fn rule_set ->
        {:ok, pid} = RuleReceiver.start_link()
        RuleReceiver.process_rule_set(pid, {rule_set, company_id, auth_headers})
      end)
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you have any code already written? Can you post that?

Comment: Above code is sufficient? result = ProcessRuleSet.process_rule_set() is the method which return response from API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> though [**`GenServer.cast/2`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#cast/2) [...] how I can **collect the responses**

You cannot per se. Cast requests are asynchronous and return **no response**. The only way to collect the data from `cast`s, would be to introduce a store (like an [`Agent`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html), or `ets`, or whatever,) and store the values directly from `cast`s. This solution has the obvious drawback: the workflow of it would be undetermined, one might not assume all the 10 responses are *processed and stored* at any time. That said, `cast`s under some circumstances might even be lost and unprocessed and you have no chance to get notified about that. I have never met such a case, but it’s considered to be legit.

So, in this particular case, you probably should just use [`GenServer.call/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#call/2) instead of `cast`, and collect responses directly in the iteration with [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2):

```
def perform() do
  Enum.map(rule_sets, fn rule_set ->
    {:ok, pid} = RuleReceiver.start_link()
    {pid, RuleReceiver.process_rule_set_call(...)}
  end)
end
```

As the result you’ll have 10 tuples `{pid, response}`. I am not sure what is the reason to create 10 `GenServer`s here and why would not you use named `GenServer`s to not bother with `pid`s, but this is obviously out of scope here.

Comment: If I use call instead cast method then I have to wait for the response, right?

Comment: Right. If you want to return immediately, use `Task.async` with `GenServer.call` and collect results later by handling task returns. There are many ways to achieve the functionality you need, and all of them require a longer answer. With `GenServer.cast` this functionality cannot be achieved.